# How to give a link from php page to another URL with a flex state?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-html-interaction

If I want to navigate directly to the second state of some flex app, for which the link has to be given from another php page. How to do it? If I give the normal URL it will anyway land me to the first state.But I want it to directly go to the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the state via flashvars. Then use whatever is passed in to define the state.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use deep-linking.  It takes a little more work but has other benefits in your applicaiton anyway.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_1.html

basically you would just give the url and put extra information on the end, something like:

http://myurl.com/myapplication.html#state=second

The other way to do it would be to pass in the state via flashvars like Zack said, and then just change your state on creationComplete.